# Push notifications are not working in the iOS build created using Azure Pipeline

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In a Xamarin.forms project I am trying to create the build using below YML script. I have added the tasks to install both Appstore distribution and APNS certificate .p12 file. whole script is working fine, Build is working fine only push notifications are not working, below is the script I am using:

```
stage: iOSBuildProd
  displayName: iOS Build Prod
  dependsOn: iOSBuildQA
  pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
  jobs:
    - job: iOSBuildSolution
      displayName: iOS Build Solution
      steps:
      - script: sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 5_0_0 
        displayName: 'Select Xamarin SDK version'
        enabled: false
      - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        displayName: installing Build certificate
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: '$(certAPNSFile)'
          certPwd: '$(certificatePassword)'
          keychain: 'temp'
          deleteCert: true  
      - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        displayName: installing Build certificate
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: '$(certDistributionFile)'
          certPwd: '$(certificatePassword)'
          keychain: 'temp'
          deleteCert: true  

      - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        displayName: installing provisioning profiles
        inputs:
          provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
          provProfileSecureFile: $(AppStoreProfileName)
          removeProfile: true
      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        displayName: 'NuGet Installer'
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: 'NuGet Command'
        inputs:
          restoreSolution: '$(solutionPath)'
      - task: XamariniOS@2
        displayName: 'iOS Build'
        inputs:
          solutionFile: '$(iOSSolutionPath)'
          configuration: '$(solutionConfiguration)'
          args: '/p:IpaPackageDir="$(outputDirectory)"'
          packageApp: true
          buildForSimulator: false
          runNugetRestore: true
          signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
          signingProvisioningProfileID: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          pathtoPublish: '$(outputDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'prodStage'
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't get Push Notifications to work. I'm using openssl to create my Apple Dev cert and my Apple Push Notification cert. They are both p12 files. I can see in the DotNetCoreCLI@2 Task that there is no mention of the push notification cert. I'm building a .Net Maui app. I also don't see any mention of push notifications in the Pre-job: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile Task. Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Based on this link, it looks like we need to combine the certs in order to create one p12 file. They are using pem, but we should be able to modify for p12. https://gist.github.com/fahied/f1dffbbea3333c7045f7

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm doing it. This works.

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'apple_dev_2022.p12' 
    certPwd: $(iOSCertPassword)
    keychain: 'custom' # Options: default, temp, custom
    customKeychainPath: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/CustomFirstKeyChain.keychain
    deleteCustomKeychain: true
    keychainPassword: $(iOSCertPassword)
  displayName: Install Development Certificate (Dev not Ad Hoc)
      
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'apple_dev_push_2022.p12' 
    certPwd: $(iOSCertPassword)
    keychain: 'custom' # Options: default, temp, custom
    customKeychainPath: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/CustomSecondKeyChain.keychain
    deleteCustomKeychain: true
    keychainPassword: $(iOSCertPassword)
  displayName: Install Push Notification Certificate

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'My_App_Dev_not_Ad_Hoc_3_v2.mobileprovision'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working using the Firebase.plugin for .Net Maui. I have no idea if the code I posted for installing two Apple Certificates fixed it. I have since tested with the APN server that I built and that works. The Firebase console works too.

If you are having issues getting Firebase.plugin to build on iOS, take a look at this issue. https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/51