# WillPresentNotification is not being called in Maui app

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I am using Firebase in my Maui app for push notification. It works on Android but I am having a problem with WillPresentNotification not being called on iOS.

I have made a new test app in iOS and it works fine but for some reason it doesn't work in my main app. I can't see what I have missed. Everything looks the same.

Any ideas? What could cause that not to fire?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WillPresentNotification is not being called in Maui app

About this issue, you can try to use Firebase.plugin to fix it. For more details, see this case: [.Net Maui iOS app with Push Notifications WillPresentNotification or DidReceiveNotificationResponse never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74101037/net-maui-ios-app-with-push-notifications-willpresentnotification-or-didreceiven).

Other things related, you can also check out these threads: [willPresentNotification not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935776/willpresentnotification-not-work-as-expected) | [Firebase Push Notifications in .NET MAUI (iOS)](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-ios-2f4388bf1ac).

Hope it can help you.

**Update**

For .NET 7, it is no longer supported, Obsolete. And as you said that the local notify code was trapping the event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but doesn't support .NET 7, so i'd say it looks abandoned at the moment. I worked out what it was in the end - the local notify code was trapping the event.

Comment: Well, I edited the wiki answer according to your reply :)